# client can get list of notes Node API(express)

Tags: node.js, express

hi im building a CRUD app using express JS only no mongoose

i have a data.json with object and 2 properties id and notes.
i need to get only the notes property into a new array so far i have

```
// load up express framework
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

// create instance of express 
const app = express();

//built in file system helper
const fs = require('fs');

const dataPath = 'data.json';


app.get('/api/notes', (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile(dataPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    
    const wholeData = JSON.parse(data);
    let result = [];
    for (let i in wholeData.notes) {
      if (i) {
        result.push(wholeData.notes[i])
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    }
    return result;
    
    
    
    
    
  })
  
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
})
```

what can i do to send the parsed data?

Comment: res.send(result);

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're asking how to send the data back to the client but if you do, you can add `res.json(<YourObject>)` which will return the object data to the client.

Here is how your code would look like:

```
app.get('/api/notes', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(dataPath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    
    const wholeData = JSON.parse(data);
    let result = [];
    for (let i in wholeData.notes) {
      if (i) {
        result.push(wholeData.notes[i])
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    }
    res.json(result);
  })
})
```

Also there is no need to add the next parameter in your Request handler since the request is being responded here.